# Laravel CustomRequest authorize, pass request data to validate the auth user customer id and the model id match

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-6

I'm trying to fix an if-else statement in the request for my controller. What I'm trying to do is: if the `auth::user-companyID == $request-companyID` then true else false; The `companyID` for the request is in a hidden field on the blade file.

**CustomRequest**

```php
public function authorize()
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    if ($user->companyID == $request->companyID) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```php
public function edit(EquipmentRequest $request, $id)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();
    $user = Auth::user();
    $equipment = EquipmentModel::where('id', '=', $id)->first();
    $equipment->Year = $request->Year;
    $equipment->Make = $request->Make;
    $equipment->Model = $request->Model;
    $equipment->Type = $request->Type;
    $equipment->unitNumber = $request->unitNumber;
    $equipment->AnnualInspectionDate = $request->AnnualInspectionDate;
    $equipment->userID = $request->userID;
    $equipment->companyID = $user->companyID;
    $e = $equipment->save();

    if ($e) {
        $request->session()->flash('success', 'The equipment was successfully updated.');
    } else {
        $request->session()->flash('error',
            'An error occurred while saving. Please refresh your browser and try again.');
    }

    return redirect()->route('equipmentlist');
}
```

This form worked before I started messing with it so I know the form is working correctly on the blade file. I'm not sure if you can pass the request data the way I'm doing it or if I have to do a construct to do it this way. I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: Have you tried `public function withValidator($validator)` method in your `CustomRequest` class ?

Answer (score 1):

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function authorize()
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    return $user->companyID === request()->companyID;
}
```

Comment: i get request does not exist